# Is this a GCC bug with storing result of bitwise operation on uint128_t in a bitfield

Tags: c++, gcc, bit-manipulation, compiler-optimization, bit-fields

This code works with GCC with less than `-O2` optimizations or in clang.

```
constexpr uint16_t KEY_BITS = 70;
constexpr unsigned __int128 KEY_BITS_MASK = (((unsigned __int128) 1) << KEY_BITS) - 1;

struct Entry
{
    unsigned __int128 left : 4;
    unsigned __int128 right : 4;
    unsigned __int128 key : KEY_BITS;
};

Entry data;

void print(unsigned __int128 a)
{
    std::cerr << std::bitset<16>(a >> 64) << std::bitset<64>(a) << std::endl;
}

void store(unsigned __int128 key, uint8_t left, uint8_t right)
{
    data.left = left;
    data.right = right;
    data.key = key & KEY_BITS_MASK;

    print(key & KEY_BITS_MASK);
    print(data.key);

    assert(data.key == (key & KEY_BITS_MASK));
}
```

In GCC with `-O2` it seems to be undefined since adding or removing the prints changes the behavior. In the "bad" case it converts the result of the `&` operation to a 64 bit integer first.

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding something about how these types should behave. It doesn't seem like it should be undefined.

Compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/he7Kx6rMr

Answer (score 0):

How bitfields are implemented is "implementation defined" and not part of the C++ standard. Meaning bitfields can be padded with extra bits to align them in memory. This means they cannot safely be used to store actual bits. They only ensure the result of setting and reading behave like the variable had the specified number of bits.

Seems [cppreference bit_field](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) also contains that information (look at the notes section)

And the C++ standard documentation on bitfields [[class.bits]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.bit), which also mentions that bit fields are implementation defined (and may or may not contain padding)

Comment: The implementation defined bitfield behavior combined with implementation extension `__int128` seems (to me) to be asking for trouble.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't depend on layout details of the bitfields in the struct; they aren't type-punning it to look at the object-representation.  They're just putting an `unsigned __int128` value into `unsigned __int128 key : KEY_BITS;` and getting it back out, and finding it truncated to 64-bit.  But the CPPreference page you linked says "*lvalue-to-rvalue conversion always produces an object of the underlying type of the bit-field.*" So `data.key` reads as an `unsigned __int128`.  They're even masking the value before assigning to the bitfield member so it's not out-of-range.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks I missed that detail (about it not being out of range).

Comment: Note that the underlying type is unsigned, so assigning an out-of-range value isn't one of the things that cppref lists as implementation-defined.  If it works like plain unsigned integer types, if the source is another integral type (not e.g. float; that's UB), the value is modulo-reduced, i.e. truncated to fit.  So I think `data.key = key` would have well-defined behaviour for any value of `key`.  And regardless, the compiler certainly has to make asm that works for values of `key` that *do* fit, which it didn't here.  (IIRC, it was just zeroing some bits past the low 64 of the field)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It zeroed out bits past the first 64. While the "type" would imply we can fit 128 and the bitfield size is also more than 64 (70 in this case). So I don't think this is supposed to be an allowed implementation.

Comment: Actually, in the current version I posted, it zeroes out past the first 56 bits and it is equal to 64 - the sum of the sizes of the left and right bitfields. However, if you put those bit fields after the key bit field in `Entry`, then it just keeps the first 64 bits.